# Error: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_x86_64DebugApkCopy'

Tags: cordova, gradle, android-billing, cordova-plugin-purchase

I know this question has been asked a dozen of times, but it seems that my problem is a little bit specific. My problem is that when running `cordova build android` I am facing the following:
[image: error message]

This seems to be related to the plugin `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`, which I need in regards to the (still not resolved) problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977751/in-app-products-not-working-anymore-in-android-devices-using-cc-fovea-cordova-pu), which very likely appears since having this plugin interim-wisely uninstalled.

In order to fix this issue I downgraded gradle from 6.x to 3.5, cordova from 8.x to 6.5.0 and cordova-android from 8.x to 6.2. - without help.

Here is a list of what I have installed:
[image: cordova plugin list]

And these are my installations:
[image: npm list -g]

Note: The folder `/Users/schumachergbr/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/billingclient` is missing; not sure this is related or not as the billing error seems to be the second in the row for me...

Any idea what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed the issue on my own by changing the cordova plugin list, which now looks as following:
[image: solution plugins]